# I have the following code to write my outputs from SQL Server using Python: output is '1', '2', '3', but I want 1 2 3

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

```
 conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};' 
        'Server=DESKTOP-IINBCRC\SQLEXPRESS;'
        'Database=employees;'
        'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
 cur = conn.cursor()
 cur.execute("select * from Login")
 for row in cur:
     print(row)
```

The output is '1', '2', '3', but I want the output to be 1 2 3

Comment: Are you sure that the output is `'1', '2', '3'` and not `['1', '2', '3']`? If it's the latter, then the output you're given is a list, so you want to "unpack" the list into the format you want to print. You could do that using something like: `" ".join(["1", "2", "3"])`

Comment: The output is ('1', '2', '3') I tried join its not working

Comment: Then your output is a `tuple` and it should work the same way: `" ".join(('1', '2', '3'))`

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 0):

So, given,

```
txt = "'1', '2', '3'"
lst=[x.strip()[1:-1] for x in txt.split(",")]
" ".join(lst)
```

this should produce (I have tested)

```
'1 2 3'
```

Or to do it a bit more smart:

```
txt=txt.replace(",","")
txt=txt.replace("'","")
```

Comment: When I am working on SQL Server its giving the right output but when am retrieving the data using Python the output is with quotes and coma.

Comment: Ok, so I guess you have a string "'1','2','3'" You can do row1 = row.split(",") and then row1[i][1:-1] for all i. The last one removes the qoutes.